# How to move copied sheet at the end of the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to move copied sheet (List) at the end of the spreadsheet?

```
 function makecopy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('List');
  var values = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss);
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[moveActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=fr-FR#moveActiveSheet%28Integer%29) is a method of the spreadsheet object

Here is an example :

```
function makecopy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('List');// you can get the sheet by its name or by its index
  var copy = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss);
  Logger.log(copy.getName());// optional, just to check the copy's name
  ss.setActiveSheet(copy);// set it active
  ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());// move it to the last position
  }
```